How can I suppress the word 'Chapter' (book) and have number and title in one line?
I am using the book class and I want the title of the chapters to be printed without the word 'Chapter' or 'Kapitel', respectively. I already succeeded in suppressing the word itself with the help of this question but now, I would like to have the number and the title in the same line like it is the case for section titles. How can I do that?
So far, I have this:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\addto\captionsgerman{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}
\end{document}

which leads to

...but I do not want the line break between number and title.
Also in the header in should be printed without an extra dot which is the case right now.
The document should remain in book-class or in something similar.

Off-topic: Are you sure, you want german? Apart from the fact that the example is rather in English and therefore english would make more sense, most authors want ngerman for German-language documents.

Thanks for your suggestions.
Yes, I want German, I just wrote English in the MWE to make it easier accessible.
And I want to remain in book class or something similar (I modified the question accordingly).

The solutions for the report class from the linked question also works for book (just replace report by book resp. scrreprt by scrbook). And scrbook is the KOMA-Script book class.

Another possible duplicate: how to suppress "chapter" in \chapter (while keeping numbering)

You can consider using Koma Script scrbook rather than book.
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{The first chapter}
\end{document}


Or you can customize the title format. Here I used titlesec
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]% Hang = sameline. Display is default
            {\huge\bfseries}% Format. Here is bold and huge size
            {\thechapter}   % Label. Here is just the chapter number
            {2ex}           % Distance between label and title
            {}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{The first chapter}
\end{document}



Just a note: If you don't want sans serif titles in the first example, you can add option sfdefaults=false.

Thanks - I changed to scrobbok which also seems to be appropriate for my case.

You can modify \@makechapterhead directly.  I put the chapter title into a \parbox to effect hanging indentation.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \Huge\bfseries\thechapter
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
        \hfill\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{% added
          \Huge \bfseries #1}\par\nobreak
      \else
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
      \fi
    \else
      \interlinepenalty\@M
      \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \fi
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}
\end{document}

